# Find a configuration for which this bound is achieved.

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics, stochastic-processes

This is the problem from David Pollard Book" Convergence of Stochastic Process".

**Can anyone give me some hint here??**

Let $S_0$ be a set of N points in $S$. Suppose there is an integer $V\leq N$ such that $D$ shatters no set of V points in $S_0$. Then $D$ picks out no more that ${n \choose 0}+ {n \choose 1}+ .....+ {n \choose {V-1}}$ subset from $S_0$

The above theorem informs us that the class of quadrants in $R^2$ picks out at most $1+\frac{1}{2}N+ \frac{1}{2}N^2$ subsets from any collection of N points. Find a configuration for which this bound is achieved.

H**strong text**ow to find Configuration for which this bound is achived??

Definition from the same book :

Let $D$ be a class of subsets of some space $S$. It is said to have
polynomial discrimination (of degree v) if there exists a polynomial $\rho(.)$ 
(of degree $v$) such that, from every set of $N$ points in $S$, the class picks out at
most $\rho(N)$ distinct subsets. Formally, if $S_0$ consists of $N$ points, then there
are at most $\rho(N)$ distinct sets of the form $S_0\bigcap d $ with$ d$ in $D$. Call $\rho(.)$ the
discriminating polynomial for $D$.

Thank you

Comment: "$D$ shatters no set of $V$ points in $S_0$"?  I have no idea what kind of thing $D$ is supposed to be, nor how such $D$ would "shatter" or not a set of points.

Comment: I added the definition of D

Comment: Couldn't get the idea ,

Comment: Thanks for adding the setup of $D$ as a family of subsets of $S$, but I still have only a vague notion of how $D$ would "shatter" (or not) a $V$-subset of points.

Comment: I also didn't understand that part. Question is making me confuse . Do you have any idea to solve this ? I mean your understanding

Comment: I looked into D. Pollard's book, "Convergence of Stochastic Processes", using Google Books preview function, and I find that the theorem you quote is high on page 19, while the definition of "shatters" is given toward the end of page 18.  A family $\mathscr D$ of subsets of points *shatters* subset $F\subset S$ if every subset of $F$ (including the empty set and all of $F$) can be expressed as $D\cap F$ for some $D\in \mathscr D$.

Comment: I checked it , you are right. Thanks . Any hints for this problem ?